# Easy map C# Models on Angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Angular 2 with C# WebApi (FW 4.5).

In C# side, I've model that I send in JSON.
In Angular, I retrieve this model, but how is possible to retrieve data structure without create another similar models in javascript ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Use use immutable js packag. If, you want to Use data structures in Angular application.

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: Good framework, but it's not really what i'm seeking. My needs is to have a "generator of class" from c# to js.